# Removing left recursion

Tags: bnf, left-recursion

I am feeling quite nostalgic so I've decided to write an adventure game creator that allows complex sentences to be entered by the user.

I have hand rolled a lexer and parser that uses the visitor pattern and it works quite well, until I encountered a left-recursion issue with one of my BNF (Backus-Naur Form) rules:

```
object          ::= {adjective} noun 
                  | object AND {adjective} noun
```

After removing the left-recursion [by following this wiki entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion) does this look right?

```
object      ::= {adjective} noun object2
object2     ::= AND {adjective noun} 
              | !Empty
```

Edited:

I am hand rolling the lexer and parser using C# by following the guide given [here](http://onoffswitch.net/a-handrolled-language-parser/).  I an not using any parser generators for this exercise.

Also, I got the BNF rules for the parser from [this website](http://www.malinche.net/howtextadventuregameswork.html).

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained what tools or algorithms you're using for parsing.  Since you're having trouble with left recursion, I deduce that you're using recursive descent, which is fine, but it would be helpful to know for sure, and what parser generator (if any) you're using.

Comment: I've updated my original question with further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason to prefer left-recursion over right recursion in this case?  Wouldn't this be simpler:

```
object ::= {adjective} noun |
           {adjective} noun AND object
```

If you really want to make your solution work, you need to make `object2` right-recursive:

```
object      ::= {adjective} noun object2
object2     ::= AND {adjective noun} object2 |
                !Empty
```

Comment: Using left-recursion is resulting in a stack overflow error and I had to change the rule to use right-recursion to get around this.  The original BNF rule for `object` only allows a single `AND`, that's why I haven't made `object2` right recursive.

Comment: The first BNF rule in your question allows one or more repetitions.  It doesn't limit the input to two repetitions.

Comment: Rob: Actually yes, you're quite correct it does allow or or more repetitions.  My mistake!  I am accepting your second answer after changing my code to follow this rule and it now works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Usually when I have this rule (yours):

```
object          ::= {adjective} noun | 
                    object AND {adjective} noun
```

I apply the following transformations:

Stage 1 (still left recursion) -

```
object          ::= ad_noun | 
                    object AND ad_noun

ad_noun         ::=  {adjective} noun
```

Stage 2 (change to right recursion) -

```
object          ::= ad_noun | 
                    ad_noun AND object

ad_noun         ::=  {adjective} noun
```